# AAD - Change notification for user password expiry

Tags: azure-active-directory

In azure active directory, is it possible to create change notification subscription against user password expiration? so that client application **PROGRAMMATICALLY** can send out advance notification email about password expiration to concern user. Please advice.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`Set-MsolPasswordPolicy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/msonline/set-msolpasswordpolicy?view=azureadps-1.0) to updates the password policy of a specified domain or tenant.

The [password policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/authentication/concept-sspr-policy#password-policies-that-only-apply-to-cloud-user-accounts) that only apply to cloud user accounts, and Password expiry notification default value is 14 days (before password expires).

> client application PROGRAMMATICALLY can send out advance notification email about password expiration to concern user.

It seems that it's impossible. You could vote this [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/32954167-password-expiry-reminder-email-notification) or give your voice in it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but sorry it is not answering my above query. My actual query  is, AAD is capable of sending change notification to the subscribed webhook if user properties like first name, last name etc get changed. Likewise, is AAD capable of sending change notification to  subscribed webhook if AAD user's password is about to expire?